# Isolating Consul by CIDR block

Tags: consul

Our Consul/Nomad environments are normally isolated by VPC and happily run by themselves all alone.  However, we need to connect the VPC's together for a while via peering connection and now Consul in both environments are discovering services in the other environment.

Is there a way I can restrict Consul's service discovery to specific CIDR blocks while leaving the VPC's fully peered?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by using AWS Network ACL to block ports 8300-8302 for both TCP and UDP on the Inbound settings for both VPCs.  In hindsight, this was pretty obvious.